# What's the best way to test if a user can sudo in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, output-redirect

Reading the sudo man page, I see that the -v flag can be used to check if the user has sudo privileges in his workstation. I have a piece of script that needs to test it. If the user has not sudo privileges, it prints on screen:

```
Sorry, user tester may not run sudo on debian.
```

How can I suppress this message and just execute the rest of the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to append `>/dev/null` in your command. In case the message is printed in stderr then use `2>/dev/null` or as advised in comments use `&>/dev/null`  to redirect both stdout and stderr to null.

Comment: You can also use `&>/dev/null` to redirect both stdout and stderr at the same time :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using sudo -l or --list
As per the man page, sudo can be used with -l or --list to get the list of allowed and forbidden commands for any particular user.

The syntax would be: sudo -l [-AknS] [-a type] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]

If we use sudo --list without any arguments, then it will print the list of allowed and forbidden commands for the user who is executing the sudo command

## sudo --list

User root may run the following commands on client:
    (ALL) ALL

Answer (score 0):

## Depends on what you mean by *"can user sudo"*

### Short answer:

If `can_auto_sudo=$(sudo -l -n sudo &>/dev/null; echo $?)` is 0, you can sudo as much as you want.

### Long Answer

- Do you need to test before or can you just handle error cases?
- How much do you need to know, the sudoers real username is a valid piece of data to want, for example.
- This question is often asking several different but related questions. So I will ask those more precisely and then answer for each.

##### 1. Is this script being run using sudo?

`[ $EUID -eq 0 ] || exit 1`  # Exit if not effectively root

##### 2. Can this user run a specific command as root using sudo?

`sudo -l /usr/bin/program &>/dev/null || exit 2`  # Exit if it can't run this as sudo

##### 3. Can this user run sudo without interacting?

`sudo -l -n  /usr/bin/program &>/dev/null || exit 3`   # Exit if requires interaction

##### 4. Can I check all that ahead of time?

`sudo -ll -U $USER    # tells you which commands can be runs with sudo by user (have to parse yourself)

##### 5. Script being run with sudo or actually root?

`[[ "$(printenv SUDO_USER)" = "" ]] || echo "$SUDO_USER is sudoing!" && exit 5`